# How to integrate Swing into JavaFX Applications?

Tags: swing, javafx-2

I have known how to embed JavaFX content into Swing applications according to this [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE).

But now I want to add some Swing components to the JavaFX Scene. Is there any ideas about that?

Regards,
Qin

Answer (score 3):

now it's possible to do that 
what you need now is install jdk 8 
because swing content in javafx is introduced in jdk8

```
@FXML
private SwingNode swingNode;
...
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(FileName, hash, connect);
swingNode.setContent(new JRViewer(jasperPrint));
```

oracle just add tutorial for this too
for the next you can follow this link
[oracle tutorial embed swing in javaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/interoperability-tutorial/embed-swing.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not possible in JavaFX 2.*, but some people hava worked on it. Take a look here : http://www.jroller.com/neugens/entry/embed_swing_inside_javafx_2 . Maybe you will find what you want. :)